# Disable Resharper with comment

Tags: c#, delegates, resharper

**Edit:** Problem is solved by updating.

---

Resharper is really annoying me and marking code that is 100% correct as wrong, it keeps wanting me to change an `Action` to an `Action<T1,T2...Tn>` when this obviously incorrect. It flashes everytime I type something so is really distracting. Is there a way to disable resharper totally inbetween two comments? Or how do you disable only for this warning?

[image]

**Edit:** There is no hint on the left to disable this using comments.

The menu that pops up when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>:

[image]

**Edit:** I found a solution, just wrap the offending lines of code in `#region RFail` and `#endregion` statements. Not ideal though.

Comment: This was one of the things I found very annoying about resharper. There is a way to do it for its suggested refactorings, but I am not sure about the built in resolver. I would look in the menu under the specific language features (dont remember the name, and I uninstalled resharper) and there are some options about intellisense appearance. It should be in there, but I believe it is a global setting not a per suggestion setting.

Comment: I have looked all over the options menu and I cannot find the option for this. I usually find `Alt+Enter` stuff really useful, so I don't want to disable it completely.

Comment: I got that error before too (with it not resolving Action) when I was using Silverlight.  Latest version of Resharper 5.1 fixed it for me.  (I'm on build 5.1.1727.12)

Comment: I am using Silverlight, I'll try and update.

Comment: Thanks Kirk, updating did the trick. I feel stupid for not trying in the first place. I feel I need to give you more than 2 rep :)

Answer (score 1):

RESharper - Options

- Code Inspection
- Settings
- Uncheck (Show the "Import namespace" action using popup)

Disables warning.

Answer (score 0):

If you click the context menu that ReSharper pops up at the left edge of the editor window, it should offer you the option to either wrap the offending code in a suitable comment or adjust the setting for that kind of alert.

Comment: That's very odd. I'd almost say it's a bug; perhaps you should report it to JetBrains. Also, would you please post a screen shot of the context menu into the question?

Comment: I don't think that there is a context menu button in this situation.

Comment: I think it is a bug, there seem to be quite a few with R#, especially with nested anonymous delegates. Only this time I can't disable the warnings.

Comment: Callum, please log any issues you find in http://youtrack.jetbrains.net and we can look into them.

Thanks.